# alternative to wp_is_mobile()

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to show a different image depending on whether you are on mobile or desktop.
I figured I could do this with the wp_is_mobile function, but Wordpress says it should not be used for styling purposes.

Real-life testing also shows that indeed it does not always work, and sometimes the desktop images is showed on mobile devices. My current code below. Where the div refers to a css class where I load the image.

I initially used @media only screen and (max-width) in my css, but then it always loads both images. What would you recommend doing as the best solution?

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    <div id="webwinkelkeur-mobile"></div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div id="webwinkelkeur-desktop"></div>
<?php endif; ?></a>
```

css part to load image from sprite

```
#webwinkelkeur-desktop{
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:45%;
    z-index:999;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background: url('/webwinkelkeur-sprite.png') 0 0;
}
#webwinkelkeur-mobile{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:999;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    background: url('/webwinkelkeur-sprite.png') 80px 40px;
}
```

Comment: You should use media queries for this. You mention that it loads both images, but they appear to be the same file?

Comment: Please share your media queries as well, I think it's the appropriate way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback.
I realized you can use the media queries and the sprites in one go.
The code then becomes:

In my **footer.php**

```
<a href="link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
<div id="webwinkelkeur-float"></div></a>
```

And in my **style.css**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 691px){
#webwinkelkeur-float{
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top:45%;
z-index:999;
width:50px;
height:100px;
background: url('webwinkelkeur-sprite.png') 0 0;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 691px){
#webwinkelkeur-float{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
z-index:999;
width:80px;
height:40px;
background: url('webwinkelkeur-sprite.png') 80px 40px;
}}
```